# Android 12 and Knox DomainFilterRule

Tags: android, samsung-knox

Is there a known issue between Android 12 and DomainFilterRules within the Knox SDK?  See https://docs.samsungknox.com/devref/knox-sdk/reference/com/samsung/android/knox/net/firewall/DomainFilterRule.html.

In testing, I am seeing some Android 12 devices block using the rules and some devices ignoring them and do not understand why.

I have set my app using the DomainFilterRule and a deny list such as *amazon.com and [www.cnn.com](http://www.cnn.com).  I was expecting to see the sites blocked on all devices using my app when using a browser such as Chrome or Firefox.  On some devices, they blocked normally.  On other devices, they weren't blocked at all.  No code was changed between devices, but they were all running Android 12.  This doesn't seem to be an issue with other versions of Android.